# Reproduce a geometric drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

How can I reproduce the following drawing using `LaTeX`?

[image: drawing]

I suspect that `TikZ` has the right instruments to do it, but I'm not  familiar with the package. Indeed, the most I can do with it is drawing basic shapes, like

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-1.9,-1.9) grid (5.9,5.9);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

or

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I don't know how to combine them to create the desired end product and how to add labels.

Comment: Dis you code something?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Yes, it is quite easy do with TikZ, but could you please add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you have tried so far? It would make easier to help you.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I've edited the question. But unfortunately I'm not familiar at all with TikZ.

Comment: It is quite easy to do in TikZ. I suggest you learn about `\coordinate` and `\node` plus see the tikz examples online. It is well worth it to learn tikz

Comment: We appreciate your effort, anyway. I added an answer. To become more familiar with TikZ, you could read a tutorial like Section 3 here: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121duck-tikz.pdf.

Answer (score 6):

There are infinite ways to do it, here's one with TikZ:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{quadro/.style={draw,              
            rectangle,
            inner sep=0pt,
            minimum height=#1,
            text width=#1},
        point/.style={draw,             
            circle,
            inner sep=1.5pt,
            fill=black}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Large, thick]
        \node[quadro={8cm}]
            (mysquare)
            {};
        \node[quadro={4cm}, draw=none,  anchor=west, text centered] (mydashed) at (mysquare.west) {$Q_{F_{j}}$};
        \draw[dashed] (mydashed.south west) -- (mydashed.south east) -- (mydashed.north east) -- (mydashed.north west);
        \node[quadro={2cm}, fill=lightgray, anchor=south, text centered] at (mysquare.south) (graysquare) {$R_{1/2}$};
        \node[point] {};
        \node[point, label=left:{$F_{j}$}] at (mysquare.west) {}; 
        \node[point] at (mysquare.south) {};
        \node[below left=.3cm and -.7cm of mysquare.south east] (descr1) {$Q_{1/2}(1/4e_{n})$};
        \draw[-Stealth] (descr1.west) -- ([shift={(.25cm,.5cm)}]graysquare.south); 
        \node[above right= .1cm and .1cm of mysquare.south east, anchor=south west]  {$x_{n}=0$};
        \node[below left= 2cm and 1.5cm of mysquare.north east] (descr2) {$e_{n}$};
        \draw[-Stealth, shorten >=0.2cm] (descr2.south east) -- (descr2.south west) -- (mydashed.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To the downvoter: it would be fair to explain why.

Comment: I totally agree with you. It's a great job for me that you've done.

Comment: I'm used to unexplained downvotes...or rather I'm a subscriber.

Answer (score 5):

A solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document}

\psset{linejoin=1, dash=3.8pt 3pt, dimen=middle}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.6, -0.9)(6.2, 4.2)
\psframe(4,4)
\psline[linestyle=dashed](0, 1.2)(2, 1.2)(2,2.8)(0,2.8)
\psframe[fillstyle =solid,fillcolor=Silver](1.4,0)(2.6,1.2)
\dotnodes(0,2){F}(2,2){G}(2,0){H}

\uput[l](F){$F_j$}
\rput[l](5,0.5){$x_n=0$}
\rput(0.7, 1.9){$Q_{F_j}$}
\pnodes(3.2, 2.7){E}(2.8,-0.4){Q}
\uput{3pt}[110](E){$e_n$\,}
\rput(2,0.6){\Rnode{R}{$R_{1/2}$}}
\rput[tl](Q){\,$Q_{1/2}(1/4e_n)$}
\psset{linewidth=0.4pt, arrows=->, arrowsize=2pt 3, arrowinset=0.12}
\ncline[nodesepB=2pt]{Q}{R}
\ncdiagg[angleA=180, nodesepB=2pt]{E}{G}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed quite simple, a beginning of a solution could be:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (3, 3) ;
        \draw [fill=gray] (1, 0) rectangle (2, 0.75) ;
        \draw [dashed] (0, 0.75) rectangle (1.5, 2.25) ;
        % $R_{1/2}$
        \node at (1.5, 0) {$\bullet$} ;
        \node [anchor=south] at (1.5, 0) {$R_{1/2}$} ;
        % $F_j$
        \node at (0, 1.5) {$\bullet$} ;
        \node [anchor=east] at (0, 1.5) {$F_j$} ;

        \node [anchor=north east] at (1, 1.5) {$Q_{F_j}$} ;
        \node [anchor=south] at (4, 0) {$x_n=0$} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I let you add the arrows.